# VBA copy value from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a cell value from one workbook to another if the cell B54 is "No", but my code does not work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop.
For i = 4 To WS_Count
   If Workbooks("Finding_Master Summary and Response Template.xlsm").Worksheets(i).Range(54, 2).Value = "No" Then
      Workbooks("finding Summary.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(3, 1).Value = Workbooks("Finding_Master Summary and Response Template.xlsm").Sheets("Response Template").Range(54, 1).Value
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

And this line does not work

```
Workbooks("finding Summary.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(3, 1).Value=Workbooks("Finding_Master Summary and Response Template.xlsm").Sheets("Response Template").Range(54, 1).Value
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does it give you an error or does it not work as expected?

Comment: You're looping with a variable `i` but you don't use that variable anywhere in the code inside the loop, so you're just doing the same thing multiple times. If there are fewer than 4 worksheets then the code inside the loop will never execute.

Comment: @Flower_Dance you wrote `Workbooks("finding Summary.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(3, 1).Value=Workbooks("Finding_Master Summary and Response Template.xlsm").Sheets("Response Template").Range(54, 1).Value` , which means you are giving it Cell A54 , is it on purpose ? and not B54 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

   ' Begin the loop.
    For i = 4 To WS_Count
       If Workbooks("Finding_Master Summary and Response Template.xlsm").Worksheets(i).Cells(54, 2).Value = "No" Then
          Workbooks("finding Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1).Value = Workbooks("Finding_Master Summary and Response Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Response Template").Cells(54, 1).Value
       End If
    Next i

End Sub
```